# Macro to FindReplace by List only replaces first element in List

Tags: excel, vba

My macro to FindReplace only replaces the first element in the Array

I cant figure out what is wrong

Thanks

```
Sub sReplace()
 'Column header for Search
 'List of words to look for
 'Word to Change elements is list to

fReplace "location", Array("Saint Paul", "SAINT PAUL", "St Paul", "St. Paul, St. Paul"), "Minneapolis-St. Paul"

End Sub
```

.

```
Sub fReplace(colHeader As String, LookFor As Variant, ReplaceWith As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Helper")

For Each aCell In LookFor
Set aCell = ws.Rows("1:1").Find(What:=colHeader, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    With ws.Range(aCell.Offset(1, 0), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, aCell.Column).End(xlUp))
         .Replace What:=LookFor, Replacement:=ReplaceWith, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End If
Next aCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
Sub sReplace()
    'Column header for Search
    'List of words to look for
    'Word to Change elements is list to

    fReplace "location", Array("Saint Paul", "SAINT PAUL", "St Paul", "St. Paul, St. Paul"), "Minneapolis-St. Paul"
End Sub
```

In array above you can remove any of `"Saint Paul", "SAINT PAUL"` because you're using `MatchCase:=False`.

And updated `fReplace` sub:

```
Sub fReplace(colHeader As String, LookFor As Variant, ReplaceWith As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim lookForVal

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Helper")

    Set aCell = ws.Rows("1:1").Find(What:=colHeader, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                                    SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        For Each lookForVal In LookFor
            aCell.EntireColumn.Replace What:=lookForVal, Replacement:=ReplaceWith, _
                                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                                        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Next lookForVal
    End If
End Sub
```

However be careful, since you're using `LookAt:=xlPart` in `Replace` method in word `"Minneapolis-St. Paul"` part `"St. Paul"` could be replaced with `"Minneapolis-St. Paul"` and you'd get `"Minneapolis-Minneapolis-St. Paul"` (because `"St. Paul"` is in `LookFor` array).

Comment: Thank all makes sense once I see how you fixed it!, Thank you

Comment: Your cautionary comment for some reason did not register the first time I read it, thanks for pointing `xlPart` out that was a oversight on my part

Answer (score 1):

Alternate (with same word of caution simoco provided)

```
Sub fReplace(sColHeader As String, varFind As Variant, sReplace As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim sFind As Variant
    Dim sFirst As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Helper")
    Set rngFound = ws.Rows(1).Find(sColHeader, ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            With Range(rngFound.Offset(1), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, rngFound.Column).End(xlUp))
                For Each sFind In varFind
                    .Replace sFind, sReplace, xlPart
                Next sFind
            End With
            Set rngFound = ws.Rows(1).Find("location", rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> sFirst
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it is always helpful to see different methods and approaches.